# Are there any sources for the idea that reincarnation is not chronological?

Tags: sources-mekorot, reincarnation

The idea of reincarnation is quite widely accepted in Judaism, but I've often wondered if there is any source for the idea that it doesn't have to happen in chronological order.  Eg. could I be (p)reincarnated as someone living at the time of David HaMelech for example?

Taking this further, this opens up another possibility - is there any source for the idea that everyone is the same soul being reincarnated in a massive series from one to another?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97344/32692

Comment: Reminds me of the movie "Predestination".

Comment: I do think Hashem can do whatever He wants and it would add to his glory to even further break the traditional concepts of time in my opinion. But I never saw a source for that concept. Reincarnation is mostly described in linear time

Comment: You mean like [this](https://youtu.be/h6fcK_fRYaI)?

Comment: @shmosel yes, although obviously without the whole concept of there being multiple "gods".  I had also considered the whole aspect of everything we do to another person, we're doing to ourself as well, and I quite like that idea